# Node SASS using importer

Tags: node.js, sass, node-sass

I'd like to compile SCSS files using importers.

My code that not works :

```js
var sassFilesMatchPatterns = [
  'styles/default/components/badge/_settings.scss',
  'styles/default/components/badge/_badge.scss'
]

var sass = require('node-sass');

sassFilesMatchPatterns.forEach(function (file) {
  sass.render({
    file: file
  }, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err + '\r\n' + JSON.stringify(result) + file);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
// _badge.scss

.badge {
  background-color: $badge-bg;
  color: text-contrast($badge-bg);
  padding: 0 15px;
  line-height: $badge-height;
  height: $badge-height;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray;
}


// _settings.scss

$black: #000;
$white: #fff;
$badge-bg: $main-color;
$badge-height: 22px;
```

Issue :

`Error: Undefined variable: "$badge-bg".
nullstyles/default/components/badge/_badge.scss`

Answer (score 0):

You need to actaually use rhe "@import setitings" at the top of the badges.scss I you're referencing variables from it

Comment: I'd like to import `_settings.scss` using my NodeJS script and not using SASS.